# Add node groups with python where the user is located

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

I am making an add-on in which many node groups can be inserted using:

```
My_NodeGroup = bpy.context.object.modifiers.active.node_group.nodes.new(type='GeometryNodeGroup')
```

The problem is that the Node Groups can only be inserted at the top, in the Geometry Nodes.

[image]

How can I make dynamically that the node group is always inserted where the user is? So e.g. In a Node Group of a Node Group?

[image]

Comment: `NodeGroup.001` is a node of type `GROUP`, so you can use `node_tree = node.id_data` which will give `NodeGroup.node_tree`

Comment: And how do I use it to add the node group to the correct group the user is in?

Answer (score 0):

Use `node.id_data` where

`node = context.active_node`

This will give you `node_tree` of the `context.active_node`

`context.active_node` is different for every `node_tree`, You have to select a node.

```
node_tree = context.active_node.id_data
node_tree.nodes.new(type='GeometryNodeGroup')
```

Comment: Context has no "active_node" attribute. And even if it did: Every group becomes active when you are in it. But groups can also be active when you are not in them.

Comment: Are you running in the python console?

Comment: Found the solution. Thank you, Karan.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in the node operator source code.

To insert a node where the user is located:

```
space = context.space_data
tree = space.edit_tree
My_NodeGroup = tree.nodes.new(type='GeometryNodeGroup')
```